# Download progress inside installation page in nsis

Tags: windows, nsis

I have an installer in MUI2/NSIS. I want to add downloading of a file to a section in the installer using inetc plugin.

Is there any way i can monitor progress in the section that are executed during the 
MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES? Show percents for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The [INetC plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Inetc_plug-in) has built-in support for a progress bar that embeds itself in the UI on the active installer page. Optionally, you can display the progress in a separate popup window if desired.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. Inet-C is a synchronous plugin and it will block the ui if i use it on a regular page. I do not want to use a separate pop-up. If i am using it in the sections how i can extract the download percentage from the plugin?

Comment: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/InetBgDL_plug-in is async but it is very hard to integrate it with the existing progressbar. I would recommend just using InetC.